# Web API Code being implemented Multiple no of times causing error for single request

Tags: asp.net-web-api2, jwt

I am working on this Web API based application ,i have implemented JWT access token for security ,after implementing JWT access token,it has developed some weird bug in the application, while testing we came to know when an android device consumes our API services,code present in controller get implemented twice or thrice, though using fiddler code works fine ,this doesn't occur always in a android device ,it occurs once while but still a big bug please help me solve this.
This is my Authorization attribute code

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.All, AllowMultiple = false, Inherited = true)]
public class CustomAuthorize : AuthorizationFilterAttribute
{
      private static bool TryRetrieveToken(HttpRequestMessage request, out string token)
       {
        token = null;
        IEnumerable<string> authzHeaders;
        if (!request.Headers.TryGetValues("Authorization", out authzHeaders) || authzHeaders.Count() > 1)
        {
            return false;
        }
        var bearerToken = authzHeaders.ElementAt(0);
        token = bearerToken.StartsWith("Bearer ") ? bearerToken.Substring(7) : bearerToken;
        return true;
    }
    private static bool SkipAuthorization(HttpActionContext actionContext)
    {
        Contract.Assert(actionContext != null);

        return actionContext.ActionDescriptor.GetCustomAttributes<AllowAnonymousAttribute>().Any()
               || actionContext.ControllerContext.ControllerDescriptor.GetCustomAttributes<AllowAnonymousAttribute>().Any();
    }
    public override void OnAuthorization(HttpActionContext actionContext)
    {
        string RefreshToken = "";
        if (actionContext.Request.Headers.Contains("Refresh-Token"))
        {
            RefreshToken = actionContext.Request.Headers.GetValues("Refresh-Token").First();
        }

        HttpStatusCode statusCode = HttpStatusCode.OK;

        string token;
        if (!TryRetrieveToken(actionContext.Request, out token))
        {
            if (!SkipAuthorization(actionContext))
            {
                statusCode = HttpStatusCode.Forbidden;

                actionContext.Response = new HttpResponseMessage();

                actionContext.Response.StatusCode = statusCode;
            }                
        }
        try
        {
            JwtSecurityTokenHandler tokenHandler =
                  new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();

            var secret = TextEncodings.Base64Url.Decode(AuthorizeKeys.SecretKey);

            TokenValidationParameters validationParameters =
                  new TokenValidationParameters()
                  {

                      ValidAudience = AuthorizeKeys.ClientID,
                      IssuerSigningKey = new InMemorySymmetricSecurityKey(secret),
                      ValidIssuer = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["AuthorizationLocalhostURI"].ToString()
                  };
            SecurityToken validatedToken;

            Thread.CurrentPrincipal =
              tokenHandler.ValidateToken(token, validationParameters, out validatedToken);
        }
        catch (SecurityTokenValidationException e)
        {

            WebClient webClient = new WebClient();

            webClient.QueryString.Add("refreshtoken", RefreshToken.Trim());
            byte[] ByteResponse = webClient.UploadValues(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["AccessTokenReGenerateURI"].ToString()
                ,"POST", webClient.QueryString);
            string JwtResponse = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(ByteResponse);

            string jsonFormattedString = JwtResponse.Replace(@"\", string.Empty);

            var JwtObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(jsonFormattedString);

            statusCode = HttpStatusCode.Forbidden;

            actionContext.Response = new HttpResponseMessage();

            actionContext.Response.StatusCode = statusCode;

            actionContext.Response.Content = new StringContent(JwtObject.ToString());
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            statusCode = HttpStatusCode.Forbidden;             
        }
   }
}
```

OTP generate controller which is causing the problem

```
public IHttpActionResult OTPSend(OTP otp)
    {

        var sms = new SMS();

        sms.GSM = otp.MobileNumber;       

        GenerateOtpService GenerateOTP = new GenerateOtpService();

        bool isMobileNumber = GenerateOtpService.IsMoblieNo(otp.MobileNumber);

        if (!isMobileNumber)
        {
            return BadRequest();
        }

        OTP OTP = new OTP();

        OTPHistory OTPHistory = new OTPHistory();

        OTP.MobileNumber = otp.MobileNumber;

        OTPHistory.MobileNumber = OTP.MobileNumber;

        if (!_OTPService.VerifyNumber(otp.MobileNumber.Trim()))
        {
            OTP.OTPCode = GenerateOTP.OtpWebRequest(sms);

            OTPHistory.OTPCode = OTP.OTPCode;

            OTP.OTPFailedReasonID = _OTPFailedReasonService.GetIdByCode(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["NewOTPRequest"].ToString());

            OTPHistory.OTPFailedReasonID = OTP.OTPFailedReasonID;

            _OTPService.Insert(OTP);

            _OTPHistoryService.Insert(OTPHistory);
        }
        else
        {
            OTP = _OTPService.GetOTPbyNumber(otp.MobileNumber);

            OTP.OTPCode = GenerateOTP.OtpWebRequest(sms);       

            OTP.OTPFailedReasonID = _OTPFailedReasonService.GetIdByCode(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["RegenrateOTPRequest"].ToString());

            _OTPService.Update(OTP);


        }
       _unitOfWork.SaveChanges();
        return Ok(OTP);
    }
```

Comment: Please provide relevant code.

Comment: Did you check using a breakpoint on API controller action to verify that if the action is really getting hit two or three times as u said?

Comment: @ManojKumar i did check using break point,whenever i try using fiddler it work perfectly fine,the problem arises when i use android device , from android device the request gets generated only once but lines of code are implemented twice or thrice i logged my code to check if request is generated twice but it is generated only once and code gets implemented many times

Comment: Which line of code? Can u share those or mention specificity in description.